# Prevent sandcastle help file builder to reorder properties alphabetically?

Tags: c#, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I have a bunch of classes with c# XML documentation comment. The properties of theses classes are in a meaningful order. When I build a .chm file with Sandcastle, the properties are listed alphabetically.

Do you know a simple way to preserve the original order?

My version is 2017.1.28.0